# Clear in regular expression php

Tags: php, regex

How I can replace string inside some text to getting this string without this "pattern"?
For example I trying replace **%%some text%%** to

```
   <span class="spoiler">some text</span>

   preg_replace("'%%[\w\s]+%%'siu",'<span class="spoiler">$0</span>',$description);
```

Comment: What is happening?  You'll probably want to use a match group so you don't have `%%`'s in your result: `preg_replace("'%%([\w\s]+)%%'siu", "<span>$1</span>", $string);`

Comment: No, I have %%'s in my result but I don't want!

Comment: My comment will remove the `%%` by taking them out of the match group: http://ideone.com/kZ7wIN

Comment: I don't see %% present anywhere in your code other than the regex itself.  It would help if you simply gave us clear examples of the input vs desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
$description = '%%some text%%';

$fixed_description = preg_replace("~%%([\w\s]+?)%%~siu",'<span class="spoiler">$1</span>',$description);

echo $fixed_description;
```

**Output:**

```
<span class="spoiler">some text</span>
```